# match a randomly chosen key to the correct value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using tkinter to create a multi-choice answer game where the user must match the correct term to the definition. So far I've managed to get four buttons up each with a randomly selected definition which has been provided from a dictionary and then added to a list so that all the definitions are in one place, I've done the same with the Terms so the term will be randomised as well. Now I'm just trying to get the program to match as least one of these buttons to have it's value match the term which is provided. Once the user presses the correct button I would have it open a new windows with a "congrats, you got it right" message.

Here is the relevant code.

```
Dictionary={"Array":"A Data Structure which holds only one data type","Assignment":"Associate names with values","Boolean":"An on or off answer, i.e Yes or No","Character":"A printed symbol","Constant":"A value which can't be altered during normal execution","Data Type":"A piece of data which is defined by the value or character(s) it is"}

Terms=(list(Dictionary.keys()))
Defs=(list(Dictionary.values()))

boot=Tk()

boot.attributes("-topmost", True)
boot.title("Count-Down!")

QuestionLabel=Label(boot, text="What is the corresponding definition to the below term?")
TermLabel=Label(boot, text=(random.choice(Terms)),bg="grey")
Answer1=Button(boot, text=(random.choice(Defs)), width=75)
Answer2=Button(boot, text=(random.choice(Defs)), width=75)
Answer3=Button(boot, text=(random.choice(Defs)), width=75)
Answer4=Button(boot, text=(random.choice(Defs)), width=75)


QuestionLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
TermLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
Answer1.grid(row=3, column=1)
Answer2.grid(row=3, column=2)
Answer3.grid(row=4, column=1)
Answer4.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of just throwing your code at us, can you show us a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? What are the relevent bits you have for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with which you could achieve what you're asking could be replacing the `random.choice()` with `random.randint(0, len(a)-1)`, where **a** is the sequence you are using(either **Terms** or **Defs**).

From the `rdDefAsInt = random.randint(0, len(a)-1)` you would get the index instead of an object, which you could then use to to get the desired object, for example `rdDef = Defs[rdDefAsInt]`, so that you can set it as the button label.

To see if the user chose the right definition for the given term, all you should do is compare the index of the term with the index of the definition and if they are equal you can present your "congrats" message.

For example:

```
termIndex = random.randint(0, len(Terms)-1)
TermLabel = Label(boot, text=(Terms[termIndex]),bg="grey")

answerOneIndex = random.randint(0, len(Defs)-1)
Answer1=Button(boot, text=(Defs[answerOneIndex]), width=75)

if answerOneIndex == termIndex:
   print('Congrats!')
```

Comment: this is great! Now as a follow up, how do I get exactly one of those buttons to show the correct answer, at the moment I'm still getting some runs when none of the four buttons have a correct answer and others where multiple buttons have the correct answers.

Comment: In that case it would be much easier to compare the actual strings and not the indices to see if the answer is correct (it's not so efficient but much easier to do). For the random term you should do the same as I mentioned above but for the definitions do the following:                       - let's say randomTerm is the random chosen term                                        `randomTermIndex = random.randint(0, len(Terms)-1)
randomTerm = Terms[randomTermIndex]`                                                            -for the Defs use this function: `random.shuffle(Defs)`

Comment: To check if the user was wrong or right you should do the following:                   `if Dictionary[randomTerm] == selectedDef:
    print('Congrats')`                                                                                                        ->  **selectedDef** is the definition chosen by the user; when you assign the label text of the buttons you should just use for example for button one ->`Answer1=Button(boot, text=(Defs[0]), width=75)`